# If $f$ is in a normed linear space and $\psi_f\in X^{**}$ defined by $\psi_f(\varphi)=\varphi(f)$ then $\|\psi_f\|_{**} = \|f\|$.

Tags: functional-analysis, normed-spaces, dual-spaces

Let $(X,\|\cdot\|)$ be a normed linear space and define $\psi_f\in X^{**}$ by the equation $\psi_f(\varphi)=\varphi(f)$ for every $\varphi\in X^*$.  Claim:  $\|\psi_f\|_{**}=\|f\|$.

Proof:  $\|\psi_f\|_{**}\le \|f\|$ is trivial from the definition.

For the reverse I tried thinking of a bounded linear functional $\varphi$ such that $|\psi_f(\varphi)|=|\varphi(f)|=\|f\|$.  But for a general space, I can't think of many interesting  bounded linear functionals that are always in the dual space.  There's the zero functional, but that doesn't help here.  I thought about the norm itself, since this is a functional, but it's not necessarily linear.

Is there a linear functional such that $\varphi(f)=\|f\|$ and we somehow linearly extend this to all other points in $X$?  Obviously we could define $\varphi(af) = a\|f\|$ for every $a\in\Bbb R$.  It would be nice to have an inner product in order to decide which vectors are orthogonal to $f$ and map them all to zero, and then use that to define $\varphi$ on a general vector.  But if we only have a norm, I don't know of a way to obtain such an inner-product.  I'm only familiar with going the other way, using the inner-product to say what the norm is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general, the won't be an inner product inducing the norm (think for example of the $\|\cdot\|_1$-norm on $\mathbf R^2$).

But there is the Hahn-Banach theorem giving you the extension you need. In the form you need it here:

> **Theorem** (Hahn-Banach). Let $X$ be a normed space, $U \subseteq X$ a subspace, $f \in U^*$. Then there is $F \in X^*$ with $F|_U = f$ and $\|F\| = \|f\|$.

The proof uses the following two steps: Some tedious calculations show that you can always extend for one extra dimension, then a Zorn's lemma argument gives you a maximal extension, what be the first step must be an extension to the whole of $X$.

To your problem: Define $\phi$ on $\mathbf R f$ as you did ($\phi(af) = a \|f\|$) and extend to $X$ using Hahn-Banach.